# Calculate the error variance in a linear regression model

Tags: regression, self-study, variance, error

I am trying to calculate the error variance for the following question but I don't have clue where to start. Could anyone please help?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This certainly looks like a homework question. Please add the "self-study" tag. See [homework questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/10812#10812)

Comment: @PeterFlom I've added the tag. It's not homework but part of my exam-preparation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(X'X)^{-1}=\dfrac{1}{150}.\left(
  \begin{array}{cc}
    5 & -10 \\
    -10 & 50 \\
  \end{array}
\right)$. $\hat{\beta}=(X'X)^{-1}X'Y=1/150.\left(
  \begin{array}{cc}
    5 & -10 \\
    -10 & 50 \\
  \end{array}
\right).\left(
  \begin{array}{cc}
    20 \\
    10 \\
  \end{array}
\right)=\left(
  \begin{array}{cc}
    0 \\
    2 \\
  \end{array}
\right)$
$\hat{\beta}\sim N(\beta,\sigma^2.(X'X)^{-1})$. You can estimate $\sigma^2$ by $s^2=\dfrac{1}{n-p-1}(y-X\hat{\beta})'(y-X\hat{\beta})$. Now if you want to simultaneously test $H_0: \beta=\beta_0$ vs $H_1:\beta\neq \beta_0$, where $\beta_0$ is a $p$-dimensional constant, then you need to use the $F$ test as follow:

$F=\dfrac{(\hat{\beta}-\beta_0)'(X'X)^{-1}(\hat{\beta}-\beta_0)}{_ps^2}\sim F_{p,n-p}$. Here $\hat{\beta}-\beta_0=\left(
  \begin{array}{c}
    -0.25 \\
    1.75 \\
  \end{array}
\right)
$.
 And $(\hat{\beta}-\beta_0)'(X'X)^{-1}(\hat{\beta}-\beta_0)=162.1875
$. Here $p=1$ and $n=N$. If we let $_ps^2=\sigma^2=1$, then $F$ statistics is 162.1875 and we need to compare it with $F_{1,N-1}$. If $P_r(F_{\alpha,1,N-1}\geq 162.1875 )\geq (1-\alpha)$ then $H_0$ cannot be rejected otherwise accept $H_1$. See e.g. page 70 of [Linear Regression Analysis: Theory and Computing](http://books.google.ca/books?id=MjNv6rGv8NIC&pg=PA71&dq=simultaneous%20confidence%20intervals%20regression&hl=en&sa=X&ei=4AVkUuD0A4aTyQHLy4CoDw&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=simultaneous%20confidence%20intervals%20regression&f=false).

Comment: Question for you... Shouldn't $s^2=\dfrac{1}{n-p-1}(y-X\hat{\beta})'(y-X\hat{\beta})$ be, instead, $s^2=\dfrac{1}{n-p}(y-X\hat{\beta})'(y-X\hat{\beta})$?